# Using Pygments with PHP (Python in PHP)

Tags: php, python, phpbb, pygments

Is it possible to use Python (specifically Pygments) with PHP? Currently, I have a phpBB forum that I'm developing for and JS Syntax Highlighters just haven't been working for me. There's already a GeSHI mod, but I want to develop something myself just for experience.

Also, would there be performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much the only way to perform that integration (with PHP as the dominant language) is to shell out.  This means starting python manually every time you need it.

That *can* be a little slow if you need to do it a lot.  You can mitigate this by creating the syntax hilite when posts are created or edited, not when viewing.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a library for this at:

http://derek.simkowiak.net/pygments-for-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in diving into **Python**, you could write an external script or server application to update new posts with syntax-highlighted code.  If it were me, I'd retain the original code in one database column and place the syntax-highlighted version in another.

A simple script to update new posts in batches could run as a cron job at whatever interval you find ideal.

To support a near real-time scenario, you could write a server application that sits and waits to be notified of new posts one at a time.  For example, upon processing a new post, the **PHP** application could send the highlighting application a message through an **AMQP** queue.